# Algorithm for all the combinations of size-n contiguous chains on a n * n board

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to write a python program to find every possible combination of placing `n` pawns on a `n * n` board so that they form a contiguous chain.

I couldn't figure out a recursive way for it. Each element can have a maximum of 4 neighbors, top and bottom, left and right.
e.g.: neighbors of the `A[i, j]` are `[i - 1, j] [i + 1, j] [i, j - 1] [i, j + 1]`

An example for the problem:
consider `n = 3` and a board as a 3 by 3 matrix(`A[3, 3]`)
some of the valid combinations are shown below:
[image: 4 examples with contiguous chains of 3 on a 3x3 board]

Is there a recursive algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Neighbours of which coordinate? Do you also give the coordinate of a point whose neighbours are to be found?

Comment: @HatimZahid No you have misunderstood the problem. I want to find every possible combination to place n neighbors on a n*n board. I only stated the condition for two elements to be neighbors.

Comment: @KellyBundy as I wrote: each element is allowed of having a **maximum** of 4 neighbors, considering that the neighbors are inside the matrix's boundary. for the element which you stated, it'll only have 2 neighbors; right and top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient and pythonic way to solve the problem, but seems clear enough to me. Imagine that the cells in your board are labeled from 0 to `n - 1`, like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Here is the code:

```
from typing import Iterable, Set, Tuple    

def find_neighbors(cur_path: Tuple, n: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    """Find the neighbors of the last cell in a path

    Args:
        cur_path: the current path
        n: board size
    Returns:
        an iterable of neighbors
    """
    cur_position = cur_path[-1]

    top_cell = cur_position - n if cur_position >= n else None
    bottom_cell = cur_position + n if cur_position < n ** 2 - n else None
    left_cell = cur_position - 1 if cur_position % n != 0 else None
    right_cell = cur_position + 1 if (cur_position + 1 ) % n != 0 else None

    return filter(lambda x: x is not None and x not in cur_path, \
                  (top_cell, bottom_cell, left_cell, right_cell))

def find_paths(cur_path: Tuple, n: int) -> Set[Tuple]:
    """find all possible paths that extend a given path so that the final length is n

    Args:
        cur_path: the given path
        n: max length of the final paths

    Returns:
        a set of paths expressed as tuples
    """

    if len(cur_path) == n:
        return {tuple(sorted(cur_path))}

    paths = set()
    for path in [cur_path + (neighbor,) for neighbor in find_neighbors(cur_path, n)]:
        paths = paths.union(find_paths(path, n))

    return paths

def find_combinations(n: int) -> Set[Tuple]:
    """Aggregates paths found from each cell of the board
    
    Args:
        n: board size

    Returns:
        All the paths that can be found in the board of length n    
    """
    combinations = set()
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            starting_position = row * n + col
            paths = find_paths((starting_position,), n)
            combinations = combinations.union(paths)
            
    return combinations

def print_board_from_path(path: Tuple, n: int):
    print("-------------------")
    [print('O' if row * n + col in path else '.', end='\n' if (col + 1) % n == 0 else ' ')\
        for row in range(n) for col in range(n)]
    print("-------------------")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 3
    for path in find_combinations(n):
        print_board_from_path(path, n)
```

The necessary functions are all documented, but let's examine them one by one, considering the board expressed from 0 to `n - 1`:

#### `find_neighbors`

This is the simplest one, very easy to understand with some examples:

```
find_neighbors(4) -> (1,3,5,7)
find_neighbors(7) -> (4,6,8)
find_neighbors(2) -> (1,5)
```

I made sure to remove out-of-board cells and those that are already present in the current path.

#### `find_paths`

This is the recursive function you are looking for:

- base case: the length of my path is already `n`, so I just need to return it as a `set` of tuple, even sorted. Why? It is a set because I do not want repeated paths, `0-1-2` is the same as `2-1-0` and only one should be included (the `sorted` path helps to avoid this situation). it is a tuple because lists cannot be keys in a set/dictionary, they are mutable objects afterall.
- recursive case: the initial set must be extended with the paths generated from each neighbor of the last cell in the current path.

#### `find_combinations`

It makes the `find_path` algorithm start from each cell in the board and `union` all the sets generated.

**Open issue**: could I avoid to start from every cell in the board? For example I do not need to start from cell 4 because the paths generated from all the other cells includes all the paths generated from 4.

## Extra

#### `print_board_from_path`

It converts the `Tuple[int]` in a board drawn by `O` (belongs to the path) and `.` (does not belong to the path).

Comment: thank you for your complete answer. about the stated issue: the problem requires to find every path and the program is already doing its job perfectly. so there's no need for further improvements  simply because it does not worth the effort of finding the cells similar to cell 4.

Comment: Nice solution, I think we can find a set of `k` points such that there does not exist any two points in the set such that there exists a path that starts from one point and ends with another, then we can skip starting from those `k` points. The reason this would work is because of the condition is satisfied, the reverse of the path would exist. But this would be a very small optimization and won't provide any significant benefits.

Comment: @Jay you are probably right, the order of magnitude definitely stays the same, and the optimization is not worth it.